# How do update one field in DB using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

```
public function checkStatus(){              
    $this->PostOffer->id = $post_offer_id;  
    if($this->PostOffer->save(array(
        'payment_status' => OrderStatus::PaymentCompleted ))) {
             $this->Order->post_offer_id = $post_offer_id;
             if($this->Order->saveField(array(
                 'payment_status' => OrderStatus::SellerPaymentComplete))) {
                  return "true"; 

               }
           }
        }
```

When I use this code PostOffer - payment_status updated on DB but 
Order - payment_status not updated in DB.

Comment: ``$post_offer_id`` is this the PK for Order Table?

Comment: $post_offer_id is not a PK in Order table..

Comment: then you need a PK in order to perform ``saveField``